# R how use a loop skipping the first interaction

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame with anova values:

```
Aval
     Df      Sum.Sq     Mean.Sq     F.value       Pr(>F)   Group1   Group2 Signif
    1  1 0.001703502 0.001703502  0.02169554 8.831391e-01   Sanger Illumina       
    2  1 3.646070790 3.646070790 28.68863997 2.403115e-07   Sanger  Pyro454    ***
    3  1 6.459171438 6.459171438 66.22950059 2.269616e-14 Illumina  Pyro454    ***
```

and I have a data frame with values

```
V
  Sanger   Illumina  Pyro454
1  2.36     2.39     2.78
```

So I want to add the max value of V data frame in this case 2.78 + 0.4 (3.18) for the first line and then increase the val at 0.2 for the rest of the rows, something like:

```
Aval
           Df   Sum.Sq     Mean.Sq     F.value       Pr(>F)   Group1   Group2 Signif  Position
        1  1 0.001703502 0.001703502  0.02169554 8.831391e-01   Sanger Illumina        3.18
        2  1 3.646070790 3.646070790 28.68863997 2.403115e-07   Sanger  Pyro454    *** 3.38
        3  1 6.459171438 6.459171438 66.22950059 2.269616e-14 Illumina  Pyro454    *** 3.58
```

if I use a loop

```
for(i in 1:nrow(A)) {
    if(i==1){
        A$position[i] <- (max(V)+0.4)
    }
    else{ 
        A$position[i] <- (A[i, 9] + (0.2*i))
    }
}
```

the results is: 3.18, 3.58 and 3.78, the problem is after the second that must be 3.38 and not 3.58; how can I fix it ?. I think that I have to add the 2.78 + 0.4 values out of the loop, and then use the for loop but skipping the first line, how can I fix it ???

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A$position[1] <- (max(V)+0.4)

for(i in 2:nrow(A)) {
     
    A$position[i] <- A$position[i-1] + 0.2
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 0.4 to `max` value of `V` and create a sequence starting from 0 with a step of 0.2 to add to each row value.

```
Aval$Position <- max(V) + 0.4 + seq(0, by = 0.2, length.out = ncol(V))
Aval

#  Df      Sum.Sq     Mean.Sq     F.value       Pr..F.   Group1   Group2 Signif Position
#1  1 0.001703502 0.001703502  0.02169554 8.831391e-01   Sanger Illumina            3.18
#2  1 3.646070790 3.646070790 28.68863997 2.403115e-07   Sanger  Pyro454    ***     3.38
#3  1 6.459171438 6.459171438 66.22950059 2.269616e-14 Illumina  Pyro454    ***     3.58
```